# Core Bluetooth State Preservation and restoration not working properly

Tags: core-bluetooth, ble-state-preservation

I have followed the state preservation and restoration in the wwdc video - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/703/

The issue Im having is that after the app is closed by the OS, when the BLE device goes out of range. The OS doesn't wake the app up like it should for 10 seconds and call the didDisconnect callback so I can call a connect function on it. Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?